# nodejs : what package can terminal show error hint

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm new in nodejs
I learn reactjs from udemy video.
And the teacher show a demo is when typing some wrong code ,it will get  a error hint by terminal :

[image]

I try it,I felt that is really cool!!
But I don't know it is caused by which package or is because I use macbook air

This is my package.json file :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^9.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-react": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-server-livereload": "1.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.4",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "node-notifier": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "reactfire": "^0.4.0",
    "reactify": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^2.4.0"
  },
```

Please guide me thank you.

Comment: Could you seriously not just check out each of those packages until you find the one? Hint, it's the one with _notifier_ in its name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was resolved in a manner that is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[node-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier)

A Node.js module for sending cross platform system notifications.